# Looks like java inner static class, but apparently it's not (I don't get it, how is this possible?)

Tags: java, android, class

From:
http://developer.android.com/resources/tutorials/views/hello-gridview.html, in ImageAdapter class:

```
imageView.setLayoutParams(new GridView.LayoutParams(85, 85));
```

Look at the **new GridView.LayoutParams** part. It seems LayoutParams is inner static class of GridView class, but according to android docs, GridView class' full path is **android.widget.GridView**, while LayoutParams is **android.widget.AbsListView.LayoutParams**. So LayoutParams is not inner static class of GridView.

How could this possible?

References:
[GridView class from android doc](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/GridView.html)
[LayoutParams class from android doc](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/AbsListView.LayoutParams.html)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

AbsListView ist the base class of GridView

Answer (score 7):

Presumably it's like this:

```
class BaseOuter {
   static class BaseInner {
   }
}

class SubOuter extends BaseOuter {
}

public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SubOuter.BaseInner x = new SubOuter.BaseInner();
    }
}
```

I'd probably suggest using the "canonical" way of referring to the nested type instead (so `BaseOuter.BaseInner` in my example) just for clarity.

Comment: While 207 gave the straight answer, you gave the explanation. Thank you very much for both of you.

Answer (score 1):

Exactly, as @Jon Skeet assumed, `LayoutParams` is inner static class of `AbsListView` and `GridView` extends `AbsListView`, thus inherits the inner class.

You could have a look at the source code on GitHub, to see exactly:

- [AbsListView.java](https://github.com/android/platform_frameworks_base/blob/master/core/java/android/widget/AbsListView.java)
- [GridView.java](https://github.com/android/platform_frameworks_base/blob/master/core/java/android/widget/GridView.java)